# Check for duplicate database entries in Sqlite 3 table (PyQt5)

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm creating an inventory management tool for IT and I am using using PyQt5 as my GUI and Sqlite to store the information in a db.

Here's how it currently looks:

[image: GUI]

As you can see, both line item 1 and line item 2 are identical entries. If I add this entry again, it will just make a third entry.

How can check if those values already exists in my database / table, and just update the quantity? In other words, have it append an existing entry IF xyz table entries have existing matches.

Thank you!

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #   BUTTONS AND WINDOW CODE HERE  #
    # ------------------------------- #
    #      Variables & Functions      #
    # ------------------------------- #
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(inventory_db)
    self.result = []

def load_data(self):
    if self.key == db_primary:
        self.result = database_1.show_table()
    elif self.key == db_secondary:
        self.result = database_2.show_table()
    self.display()

def display(self):
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(self.result):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            # format the cell information
            data = str(data)
            if "\n" in data:
                data = data.replace("\n", "")
            else:
                pass
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number,
                                     QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
            self.tableWidget.resizeColumnToContents(0)
            self.tableWidget.resizeColumnToContents(2)
            self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()

def select_table(self):
    self.key = self.item_info_window.pageCombo.currentText()
    if self.key == db_primary:
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(11)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
        (lb_id, lb_site, lb_location, lb_product, lb_make,
         lb_asset, lb_reference, lb_assigned, lb_status, lb_date, lb_info))
    elif self.key == db_secondary:
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(11)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
        (lb_id, lb_site, lb_location, lb_product, lb_make,
         lb_asset, lb_reference, lb_assigned, lb_status, lb_date, lb_info))
    self.load_data()
    return self.key

def insert(self):
    if self.key == db_primary:
        description = self.item_info_window.assettag_db1.text()
        location = self.item_info_window.location_db1.currentText()
        product = self.item_info_window.product_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.product_db1.currentIndex())
        package = self.item_info_window.package_db1.text()
        assigned = self.item_info_window.assigned_db1.currentText()
        manufacturer = self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.currentIndex())
        status = self.item_info_window.status_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.status_db1.currentIndex())
        dates = self.item_info_window.dates_db1.text()
        notes = self.item_info_window.notes_db1.text()
        user = self.item_info_window.site_db1.currentText()
        database_1.add_row(user, location, product, manufacturer, description, 
        package, assigned, status, dates, notes)
    elif self.key == db_secondary:
        description = self.item_info_window.description_db2.text()
        location = self.item_info_window.location_db2.text()
        product = self.item_info_window.product_db2.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.product_db2.currentIndex())
        package = self.item_info_window.package_db2.text()
        assigned = self.item_info_window.assigned_db2.text()
        manufacturer = self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db2.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db2.currentIndex())
        status = self.item_info_window.status_db2.text()
        dates = self.item_info_window.dates_db2.text()
        notes = self.item_info_window.notes_db2.text()
        database_2.add_row(location, description, package, product,
                             manufacturer, assigned, status, dates, notes)
    self.load_data()

def clear(self):
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
    if self.key == db_primary: 
        self.item_info_window.item_db1_id_label.setText(lb_id)
        self.item_info_window.assettag_db1.clear()
        self.item_info_window.part_number_db1.clear()
        self.item_info_window.package_db1.clear()
        self.item_info_window.value_db1.clear()
        self.item_info_window.amount_db1.clear()
        self.item_info_window.notes_db1.clear()

    elif self.key == db_secondary:
        self.item_info_window.item_db2_id_label.setText(lb_id)
        self.item_info_window.description_db2.clear()
        self.item_info_window.location_db2.clear()
        self.item_info_window.package_db2.clear()
        self.item_info_window.assigned_db2.clear()
        self.item_info_window.status_db2.clear()
        self.item_info_window.dates_db2.clear()
        self.item_info_window.notes_db2.clear()
    
def search(self):
    if self.key == db_primary:
        description = self.item_info_window.assettag_db1.text()
        location = self.item_info_window.location_db1.currentText()
        product = self.item_info_window.product_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.product_db1.currentIndex())
        package = self.item_info_window.package_db1.text()
        assigned = self.item_info_window.assigned_db1.text()
        manufacturer = self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.currentIndex())
        status = self.item_info_window.status_db1.currentText()
        dates = self.item_info_window.dates_db1.text()
        notes = self.item_info_window.notes_db1.text()

        self.result = database_1.search_rows(
            description, location, product, package, assigned, manufacturer, status, dates, notes)

    elif self.key == db_secondary:
        description = self.item_info_window.description_db2.text()
        location = self.item_info_window.location_db2.text()
        product = self.item_info_window.product_db2.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.product_db2.currentIndex())
        status = self.item_info_window.status_db2.text()
        dates = self.item_info_window.dates_db2.text()
        notes = self.item_info_window.notes_db2.text()
        self.result = database_2.search_rows(
            description, location, product, status, dates, notes)

    self.display()

def search_item(self, id):
    id = self.search_box.text()
    try:
        if self.key == db_primary:
            first_matched_item = database_1.search_row(id)
            self.item_info_window.item_db1_id_label.setText(
                "Item id:{:>35}".format(id))
            self.item_info_window.location_db1.setCurrentText(
                str(first_matched_item[1]))
            self.item_info_window.assettag_db1.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[2]))
            self.item_info_window.product_db1.setCurrentText(
                first_matched_item[3])
            self.item_info_window.package_db1.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[4]))
            self.item_info_window.assigned_db1.setCurrentText(
                str(first_matched_item[6]))
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.setCurrentText(
                first_matched_item[5])
            self.item_info_window.status_db1.setCurrentText(
                str(first_matched_item[7]))
            self.item_info_window.dates_db1.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[8]))
            self.item_info_window.notes_db1.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[9]))
        elif self.key == db_secondary:
            first_matched_item = database_2.search_row(id)
            self.item_info_window.item_db2_id_label.setText(
                "Item id:{:>35}".format(id))
            self.item_info_window.location_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[1]))
            self.item_info_window.description_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[2]))
            self.item_info_window.product_db2.setCurrentText(
                first_matched_item[4])
            self.item_info_window.package_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[3]))
            self.item_info_window.assigned_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[6]))
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db2.setCurrentText(
                first_matched_item[5])
            self.item_info_window.status_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[7]))
            self.item_info_window.dates_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[8]))
            self.item_info_window.notes_db2.setText(
                str(first_matched_item[9]))
    except Exception:
        if self.key == db_primary:
            self.item_info_window.item_db1_id_label.setText("Item id:")
        elif self.key == db_secondary:
            self.item_info_window.item_db2_id_label.setText("Item id:")
        QMessageBox.information(
            QMessageBox(), "Search", "Can not find the item")

def update(self):
    id = self.search_box.text()
    if self.key == db_primary:
        description = self.item_info_window.assettag_db1.text()
        location = self.item_info_window.location_db1.currentText()
        product = self.item_info_window.product_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.product_db1.currentIndex())
        package = self.item_info_window.package_db1.text()
        assigned = self.item_info_window.assigned_db1.currentText()
        manufacturer = self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db1.currentIndex())
        status = self.item_info_window.status_db1.currentText()
        dates = self.item_info_window.dates_db1.text()
        notes = self.item_info_window.notes_db1.text()
        database_1.update_row(id, description, location, product,
                               package, assigned, manufacturer, status, dates, notes)

    elif self.key == db_secondary:
        description = self.item_info_window.description_db2.text()
        location = self.item_info_window.location_db2.text()
        product = self.item_info_window.product_db2.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.product_db2.currentIndex())
        package = self.item_info_window.package_db2.text()
        assigned = self.item_info_window.assigned_db2.text()
        manufacturer = self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db2.itemText(
            self.item_info_window.manufacturer_db2.currentIndex())
        status = self.item_info_window.status_db2.text()
        dates = self.item_info_window.dates_db2.text()
        notes = self.item_info_window.notes_db2.text()
        database_2.update_row(id, description, location, product,
                               package, assigned, manufacturer, status, dates, notes)

    QMessageBox.information(
        QMessageBox(), "Update", "Item has been updated.")
    self.load_data()
```

Comment: Before insert you can search for an entry with the same data and reject insert if found.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's what I'm thinking - but having a hard time considering what the best way to implement that would be. I would have to parse through my existing table on at least a couple of those parameters (like product, manufacturer, description) and if found, update them. I have a separate update function, but it requires a line number and manual intervention. I'm having a hard time considering how this can be done seamlessly. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Use a `select` that looks in the database for all fields *except* for the quantity. If the cursor returns a result, then the item exists, and you can use the id for that. Note that you should properly use a PRIMARY KEY, which would make everything easier. Also consider using the QtSql module and QDataWidgetMapper.

Comment: Decide which columns make a record unique, then add a unique index over those columns.  Trying to add a second record will raise an exception which you can catch and handle in a try/except block..